# Groovy can not encodeAsHTML()

Tags: html, grails, groovy, textarea

I'm using grails 2.4.3. When I input data to textarea, with new line and save to db. After that, I load it to the view, replace new line by break. However, it shows `<br>` instead of break.

Below is code I used:

```
${book.introduction.encodeAsHtml().replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,"<br />")}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you trust the output, there are multiple ways of doing this:

As another answer suggests:

```
${raw(book.introduction.encodeAsHtml().replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,"<br />"))}
```

With the `encodeAsRaw()` method:

```
${book.introduction.encodeAsHtml().replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,"<br />").encodeAsRaw()}
```

Using Grails' taglibs:

```
<g:encodeAs code="Raw">${book.introduction.encodeAsHtml().replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,"<br />")}</g:encodeAs>
<g:encodeAs code="None">${book.introduction.encodeAsHtml().replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,"<br />")}</g:encodeAs>
```

Answer (score 2):

The new XSS prevention by default encodes all `${}` strings as HTML, so your end product is getting encoded.

You can wrap the whole output in `raw` to avoid this:

```
${raw( book.introduction.encodeAsHtml().replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,"<br />") )}
```

See http://grails.org/doc/2.4.3/guide/single.html#xssPrevention for more details. It's worth thinking about what you're rendering and whether XSS could be an issue for you in that place.